# Overfull hbox in matrix

Tags: margins, matrices

I am typing up a technical report that contains many large matrices. I am looking for a way to print these matrices with an equation number next to them without getting an overfull \hbox error.

I was thinking it might be possible to temporarily alter the page margins for the matrix. I don't really want to use smaller text as the matrix then starts becoming a little hard to read. This is currently what my matrix looks like. Any suggestions would really be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

My code in creating the above matrix is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}    

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \textbf{k}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{EA}{L} & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-EA}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3} & 0& 0& 0& \frac{6EI_z}{L^2} & 0& \frac{-12EI_z}{L^3} & 0 & 0& 0 &\frac{6EI_z}{L^2}  \\
         & & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3} & 0& \frac{-6EI_y}{L^2} & 0& 0& 0& \frac{-12EI_y}{L^3} & 0& \frac{-6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 \\
         & & & \frac{GI_p}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-GI_p}{L} & 0 & 0 \\
         &  & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L}& 0 & 0& 0 & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2}& 0 & \frac{2EI_y}{L}  & 0 \\
         &  & & &  & \frac{4EI_z}{L} & 0 & \frac{-6EI_z}{L^2}& 0 & 0  & 0  & \frac{2EI_z}{L} \\
         &  &  &  & &  & \frac{EA}{L}  & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
         & & &  & & &  & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3}  & 0  & 0 & 0   & \frac{-6EI_z}{L^2} \\
         &   &  &  &  & & &  & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3}  & 0  & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2}  & 0 \\
         & &   & &  & & & &  & \frac{GI_p}{L}  & 0 & 0  \\
         & &  & & &  & & & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L}& 0  \\
         symm. & &  &   &  &  &  &  & &  && \frac{4EI_z}{L}                   
    \end{bmatrix}
    \label{kmat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide the community with some code to replicate your current problem. It'll make it easier to start getting solutions your way. That is, help us to help you. Your code should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: it looks like the columns could be a bit narrower, so you could decrease the inter-column space just a bit.  and the "symm." at the bottom left could be inserted in the first column with a `\mathclap` (requires `\mathtools`) so that it doesn't affect the horizontal spacing.

Comment: Or reduce \arraycolsep.  Or you could switch to landscape using pdflscape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I stopped symm extending the first column (don't use math italic for multi-letter words)
and reduced the column padding a bit:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
    \textbf{k}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{EA}{L} & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-EA}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3} & 0& 0& 0& \frac{6EI_z}{L^2} & 0& \frac{-12EI_z}{L^3} & 0 & 0& 0 &\frac{6EI_z}{L^2}  \\
         & & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3} & 0& \frac{-6EI_y}{L^2} & 0& 0& 0& \frac{-12EI_y}{L^3} & 0& \frac{-6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 \\
         & & & \frac{GI_p}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-GI_p}{L} & 0 & 0 \\
         &  & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L}& 0 & 0& 0 & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2}& 0 & \frac{2EI_y}{L}  & 0 \\
         &  & & &  & \frac{4EI_z}{L} & 0 & \frac{-6EI_z}{L^2}& 0 & 0  & 0  & \frac{2EI_z}{L} \\
         &  &  &  & &  & \frac{EA}{L}  & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
         & & &  & & &  & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3}  & 0  & 0 & 0   & \frac{-6EI_z}{L^2} \\
         &   &  &  &  & & &  & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3}  & 0  & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2}  & 0 \\
         & &   & &  & & & &  & \frac{GI_p}{L}  & 0 & 0  \\
         & &  & & &  & & & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L}& 0  \\
         \rlap{\textit{symm.}} & &  &   &  &  &  &  & &  && \frac{4EI_z}{L}                   
    \end{bmatrix}
    \label{kmat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well, you were quicker than i was.  the only differences in what i came up with were `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{.5\arraycolsep}` and using `\tag(2.1)` to show that it could accommodate a wider equation number.

Answer (score 0):

A TABstack can do it without overfull boxes.  The intercolumn gap and interrow baseline skip are set, respectively, with

```
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\setstackgap{L}{1.4\baselineskip}
```

EDITED to `\rlap` the "symm.", both to not have it affect the column size and to put it as text.

The MWE is thus:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\setstackgap{L}{1.4\baselineskip}
    \textbf{k}
    =
    \bracketMatrixstack{
        \frac{EA}{L} & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-EA}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3} & 0& 0& 0& \frac{6EI_z}{L^2} & 0& \frac{-12EI_z}{L^3} & 0 & 0& 0 &\frac{6EI_z}{L^2}  \\
         & & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3} & 0& \frac{-6EI_y}{L^2} & 0& 0& 0& \frac{-12EI_y}{L^3} & 0& \frac{-6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 \\
         & & & \frac{GI_p}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-GI_p}{L} & 0 & 0 \\
         &  & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L}& 0 & 0& 0 & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2}& 0 & \frac{2EI_y}{L}  & 0 \\
         &  & & &  & \frac{4EI_z}{L} & 0 & \frac{-6EI_z}{L^2}& 0 & 0  & 0  & \frac{2EI_z}{L} \\
         &  &  &  & &  & \frac{EA}{L}  & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
         & & &  & & &  & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3}  & 0  & 0 & 0   & \frac{-6EI_z}{L^2} \\
         &   &  &  &  & & &  & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3}  & 0  & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2}  & 0 \\
         & &   & &  & & & &  & \frac{GI_p}{L}  & 0 & 0  \\
         & &  & & &  & & & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L}& 0  \\
         \rlap{symm.} & &  &   &  &  &  &  & &  && \frac{4EI_z}{L}                   
    }
    \label{kmat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this method in mind for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

And if you really need lots of space...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

\begin{equation}\arraycolsep=1em
    \textbf{k}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{EA}{L} & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-EA}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3} & 0& 0& 0& \frac{6EI_z}{L^2} & 0& \frac{-12EI_z}{L^3} & 0 & 0& 0 &\frac{6EI_z}{L^2}  \\
         & & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3} & 0& \frac{-6EI_y}{L^2} & 0& 0& 0& \frac{-12EI_y}{L^3} & 0& \frac{-6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 \\
         & & & \frac{GI_p}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-GI_p}{L} & 0 & 0 \\
         &  & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L}& 0 & 0& 0 & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2}& 0 & \frac{2EI_y}{L}  & 0 \\
         &  & & &  & \frac{4EI_z}{L} & 0 & \frac{-6EI_z}{L^2}& 0 & 0  & 0  & \frac{2EI_z}{L} \\
         &  &  &  & &  & \frac{EA}{L}  & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
         & & &  & & &  & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3}  & 0  & 0 & 0   & \frac{-6EI_z}{L^2} \\
         &   &  &  &  & & &  & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3}  & 0  & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2}  & 0 \\
         & &   & &  & & & &  & \frac{GI_p}{L}  & 0 & 0  \\
         & &  & & &  & & & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L}& 0  \\
         symm. & &  &   &  &  &  &  & &  && \frac{4EI_z}{L}                   
    \end{bmatrix}
    \label{kmat}
\end{equation}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: landscape]

You CAN change the margin temporarily using a minipage and negative \hspace, but it would be wrong.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}

\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\medskip

\noindent\hspace{-.25in}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth+.5in}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\begin{equation}
    \textbf{k}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{EA}{L} & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-EA}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3} & 0& 0& 0& \frac{6EI_z}{L^2} & 0& \frac{-12EI_z}{L^3} & 0 & 0& 0 &\frac{6EI_z}{L^2}  \\
         & & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3} & 0& \frac{-6EI_y}{L^2} & 0& 0& 0& \frac{-12EI_y}{L^3} & 0& \frac{-6EI_y}{L^2} & 0 \\
         & & & \frac{GI_p}{L} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-GI_p}{L} & 0 & 0 \\
         &  & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L}& 0 & 0& 0 & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2}& 0 & \frac{2EI_y}{L}  & 0 \\
         &  & & &  & \frac{4EI_z}{L} & 0 & \frac{-6EI_z}{L^2}& 0 & 0  & 0  & \frac{2EI_z}{L} \\
         &  &  &  & &  & \frac{EA}{L}  & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
         & & &  & & &  & \frac{12EI_z}{L^3}  & 0  & 0 & 0   & \frac{-6EI_z}{L^2} \\
         &   &  &  &  & & &  & \frac{12EI_y}{L^3}  & 0  & \frac{6EI_y}{L^2}  & 0 \\
         & &   & &  & & & &  & \frac{GI_p}{L}  & 0 & 0  \\
         & &  & & &  & & & & & \frac{4EI_y}{L}& 0  \\
         symm. & &  &   &  &  &  &  & &  && \frac{4EI_z}{L}                   
    \end{bmatrix}
    \label{kmat}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\hspace{-.25in}

\end{document}
```

[image: changing margins]