# How to change the text area of a particular page

Tags: spacing, width, text, textwidth

I have very long (horizontally) equations on a page in the middle of my document.

I have used

```
\eject\pdfpagewidth=14in
```

to change the width of that page, but I can't figure out how to change the text width of that page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try with the `adjustwidth` environment of `changepage`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287239/temporarily-change-equation-margin, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306514/how-to-align-table-so-that-it-doesnt-overflow-the-page-horizontally

Comment: it is easier to overlap the margins than change them.  There are lots of ways to do that, the simplest using negative \hspace* and a minipage.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233619/overfull-hbox-in-matrix/233631?r=SearchResults&s=1|36.2643#233631